# Compare two set of ratios

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, ratio

I'm looking for a statistical test to compare two set of ratios. For example

```
A = [(2,13), (10,50), (23, 86), (33, 133)]
B = [(6,10), (21,33), (30,62), (44,80)]
```

Where A, B are sets of tuples that represent proportions p,q.

Any clue guys?

Cheers,
G

Comment: How would you like to compare them?  According to what measure?  What would your null hypothesis be?  What assumptions are you making about the process that produced these data?

Comment: Is 2 the observed count and 13 the number of trials for the first entry in A, and similar for the rest? If this is the case and you've assumed that the success probability is same in all events within A and within B and you want to compare these 2 ratios, then a binomial test of proportions seems like what you want.